# Is there benefit to converting my program text-file output to xml-output?

Tags: xml, fortran

I have a Fortran program that outputs simulation data by writing enormous text files.  The text files will give fluid-property data for collections of mesh cells and conductor data for collections of conductor mesh cells.  So something like the following example.

```
Cell Group 1
Axial Level | Pressure | Temperature | Velocity
1           | 150.1    | 198         | 3.5
2           | 150      | 200         | 3.5
...         | ...      | ...         |

Cell Group 2
Axial Level | Pressure | Temperature | Velocity
1           | 150.1    | 201         | 3.5
2           | 150      | 205         | 3.5
...         | ...      | ...         |

Conductor Group 1
Axial Level | Conductivity | Temperature 
1           | 19.8         | 301         
2           | 19.7         | 305          
...         | ...          | ...
```

Typically, we would want to organize this data into some graphical way in order to interpret or present it.  For example, I might want to know what the change in pressure is for Fluid-Cell Group 1,302.  To get this information, I would do one of the following:

1. Re-write the output subroutine of my Fortran program so that it gives me the specific data that I want in a table that I could use GNUplot to graph.
2. Write a Python script to grab output from the text file and write it to a new file that I can work with using GNUplot.
3. Copy and paste the data into spreadsheet software and build a plot that way.

I have started to encounter XML being used in some projects I'm involved with, but I know almost nothing about it.  I want to figure out if it would be worth my time to learn about XML and start adding the capability to this Fortran program to write its data in XML format.  Can my previous method for analyzing simulation data be improved upon by making it easier, faster, and more automatable if I started writing data to XML?  If so, how, and how should I get started?

Answer (score 7):

I agree with Kevin, there's little point in writing XML unless your downstream toolchain reads XML.

I suggest that you consider instead [HDF5](http://www.hdfgroup.org/HDF5/) which is a widely used format for scientific datasets.  The HDF Group publish bindings for C, C++, Fortran and Java (if memory serves me well) but a lot of other languages/systems can read and write HDF5 files, including Python, Matlab, Mathematica, IDL and a number of the open-source scientific visualisation tools including ParaView. I haven't ever found a straightforward way of using GNUPlot on HDF5 files.

And if you really want XML  `h5dump`, one of the utilities provided by the HDF Group, can transform an HDF5 file into XML.

Comment: I've never heard of HDF5 before, so thank you for the suggestion.

Comment: My own impression is that both HDF and netCDF are quite unpopular and that the wheel gets reinvented countless of times when it comes to exporting data (also known as the "not invented here" syndrome).

Comment: Well, given the choice between XML and HDF5 for large O(100GB) numeric data sets, I know which one I'll choose every time ...

Answer (score 2):

The format of your data output is directly related to the input that your downstream processes require.  Writing XML when the only thing you have as a reader is a .csv process would be silly.

If you are finding that your readers request XML then, by all means, learn XML and start writing that way.

Learn what you need to learn, keep yourself current and go on from there.

Comment: Yes. Unless something downstream wants XML, the only advantage I can see in using XML output is that you could also learn XSLT and build transforms for a variety of different purposes -- this could replace your rewriting of the output subroutine of your Fortran program, separating the data generation from the formatting. XSLT could fairly trivially transform XML output to GNUplot input, or an HTML page, or whatever.

Comment: @MattGibson - I hadn't even thought of the XSLT angle, good point!

Comment: Well, it's kind of the lack of a downstream process that I'm trying to remedy.  This overly hands-on approach of creating plots is time consuming and not very automatable.  I read a bit about parsers, but I'm still not too sure of what they do outside of reading XML data.  I'm wondering if there's one that I can use to read my simulation data and re-organize it quickly into forms that can be better used or even create plots of specific data at my request.  Perhaps this XSLT might be that magic bullet?  I'll have to do some research on it.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to view your data in graphical form, then vtk or silo formats are likely to be what you need. They are specifically designed for representing data produced on a mesh by scientific software. Using software such as [visit](https://wci.llnl.gov/codes/visit/), you can then view the files, compare multiple runs (which it sounds like you want to do) and so forth. [This document](https://wci.llnl.gov/codes/visit/2.0.0/GettingDataIntoVisIt2.0.0.pdf) describes how to get your data into these formats, and should give an indication of the effort required and whether it is worthwhile for your problem.

This is related to @HighPerformancemark's suggestion to use the HDF5 format. However HDF5 is quite a flexible format, and you cannot expect plotting software to interpret arbitrary data in HDF5 form. silo uses HDF5 for its storage, but has a specific format for how meshes and field data should be stored. vtk is similar, but is based on xml instead.

Comment: Actually, I did add some capabilities to write data to VTK and I have opened these files with VisIt.  This allows me to view the mesh and a contour of the scalar variables in 3-D.  This is nice functionality to have, but when comparing specific parameters between two simulations or between simulation and experiment, it is more useful to be able to easily make a 2-D plot.  For example, drag on a single surface vs axial height.  I'm not aware if this is possible using VisIt or with the VTK files I created in any straightforward way.

Comment: Visit has a feature designed for plotting multiple time steps in a simulation. If you add sequential numbering to the filenames, they can all be loaded as one data set. This allows you to for example animate through them, and I think it should be possible to plot some derived quantity as a function of "time". Of course the variable which changes can be anything and doesn't need to be time.